# Why do we seek to minimise $||\vec{w}||^2 / 2$ when the margin for an SVM is $2 / ||\vec{w}||$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

According to this [article](https://medium.com/@tarlanahad/linear-svm-classifier-step-by-step-theoretical-explanation-with-python-implementation-d86c4973dc33), the following applies to the margin for an SVM:
To maximise the margin we must maxmise $2 / ||\vec{w}||$ and to do that one must minimise $\vec{w}$ and then minimise  $||\vec{w}||^2 / 2$.
Where does the square come from? How is it derived?

Comment: Maximizing $2/\|w\|$ is equivalent to minimizing $\|w\|^2/2$. (It is also equivalent to many other things, like minimizing $\|w\|^5$ or maximizing $30/\|w\|^7$.) The choice of using $\|w\|^2/2$ is for mathematical convenience: a quadratic objective function has simple gradients.

Comment: Is the 1/2 in order to have $dL/dw = w$ and not $dL/dw = 2w$?

Comment: Yes that's right, another small convenience that ultimately does not really matter too much.